# use locale (ltr/rtl) for gravity in TextView

Tags: android, layout, right-to-left

I have a simple TextView which should have `android:gravity="left"` for ltr system locales and `android:gravity="right"` for rtl system locales.

The obvious choice would be: `android:gravity="start"` but then e.g. english text will always be left-aligned and hebrew right-aligned.

Here is how it looks with `android:gravity="start"`:

LTR locale:

```
|          לורם|   // incorrect
|test           |  // correct
```

RTL locale:

```
|          לורם|  // correct
|test           |  // incorrect
```

it's supposed to look like that:

LTR locale:

```
|לורם           |  
|test            |
```

RTL locale:

```
|          לורם|  
|           test|
```

Is it possible to do that without using a layout-ldrtl folder with a modified xml file? This would complicate development a lot because I would have to edit a lot of layout files twice...

*edit:* a solution for API 17+ is enough.
I wrote system locale, but actually I'm allowing the user to change the app language like that:

```java
Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
configuration.setLayoutDirection(selectedLocale);
configuration.locale = selectedLocale;
context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

so it would be great if this locale would be considered for the rtl <-> ltr choice.

Comment: English text is rendered left to right i think with gravity start

Comment: yes, exactly that is my problem. Is there a way of forcing RTL when the RTL locale is set?

Comment: have tried adding the textdirection attribute? but its only for api 17+ i think

Comment: @Bhargav good advice. If I set it to `android:textDirection="locale"` its aligned regarding the system locale, but not the "app locale", see my edit... Sorry for the confusion, I was trying to simplify...

Comment: another problem I noticed with `textDirection` is that if you use `android:ellipsize` and force RTL `textDirection` the "..." will be placed on the left side, even for english... This looks totally wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using this solution now, I would prefer a simple xml solution, but this seems minimal so far:

```
if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
  if (DynamicLanguage.getLayoutDirection(getContext()) == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
    this.textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
  } else {
    this.textView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 77):

I had this problem too, you can use these properties with the TextView

```
android:textDirection="locale"
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```

or just add it to the Base App Theme in **styles.xml**`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">gravity</item>
    <item name="android:textDirection">locale</item>
    </style>`
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! textDirection and textAlignment works almost perfectly for me! (It's 17+ only but that's fine for this question)

Comment: The `textDirection` parameter overrides the default behavior where the text direction is determined based on the first strong character. This can cause unexpected bugs, such as "Hello!" being shown as "!Hello" in RTL layout direction. The `textAlignment` parameter has no effect since it's the default behavior. Be careful before using this if you don't completely understand the implications, overriding system's default behavior without proper consideration is always dangerous.

Comment: I strongly recommend using `textAlignment="viewStart"` mentioned in the other answer. This will not cause the above mentioned bug. But better use it only locally for the Views which need such behavior. If used globally this will override the `gravity` parameter in all `TextView`s, possibly causing UI bugs.

Answer (score 43):

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"    
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

If text view is stretched to parent width, there is no need to change the gravity of the element. Just align the text to the view start, the text will move to LTR or RTL position, independent of the text content (hebrew or western).

Comment: Thanks! This is the only answer that worked in case of `match_parent` for width and programmatically set rtl language

Comment: Make sure you have `android:supportsRtl="true"` in your AndroidManifest.xml. Otherwise, it won't work even in the AS preview.

Comment: This is better and safer solution than overriding `textDirection`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need a special extended TextView class for that:

```
public class LocaleAwareTextView extends TextView {
    public LocaleAwareTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setGravity(getResources().getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL ? Gravity.RIGHT : Gravity.LEFT);
    }
    public LocaleAwareTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setGravity(getResources().getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL ? Gravity.RIGHT : Gravity.LEFT);
    }

    public LocaleAwareTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setGravity(getResources().getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL ? Gravity.RIGHT : Gravity.LEFT);
    }

}
```

... and use this class in your layouts. If you want to switch the locale and all orientations on the fly, you will need to reload your layouts.

Answer (score 1):

It works for both LTR and RTL text. In case you want English text to be RTL in case of Arabic, it works fine.

```
android:textDirection="locale"
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```